# Search for a particular field in a array object and put it in another array for displaying a table in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I am new to angular I am getting an object array as a response from the server I need to search if any of the arrays have same key value and then put the corresponding array element values in another array for displaying it in a table.
My scenario I am passing Inquiry Number as my input Eg: 10002
My Inquiry response contains the following details Inquirydocumentno, inquirydate, materialno, name of materialinquired etc..,
My actual Response is

```
[
{
InquiryDate: ["2015-03-04"]
InquiryType:["A"]
MaterialNo: ["30"]
Material Name: ["Chair"]
InquiryDocument No: ["0010000012"]
},
{
InquiryDate: ["2019-03-04"]
InquiryType:["A"]
MaterialNo: ["31"]
Material Name: ["Book"]
InquiryDocument No: ["0010000015"]
},
{
InquiryDate: ["2019-03-04"]
InquiryType:["A"]
MaterialNo: ["31"]
Material Name: ["Bag"]
InquiryDocument No: ["0010000015"]
},
{
InquiryDate: ["2015-05-19"]
InquiryType:["A"]
MaterialNo: ["34"]
Material Name: ["lamp"]
InquiryDocument No: ["0010000018"]
}
]
```

Here In this response the details such as Inquiry date and inquiry documentno, inquiry type are fixed as header details and need to be displayed as header table whereas material no and material name are item details need to be displayed in another table on click the corresponding inquirydocument no it should display all related item details for it.
Eg: InquiryDocumentNo: 0010000015 appears two times in the response I need to be displayed it as one time in header table and on clicking a buuton details it should display the 2 item(Bag, Book) inquired in another table.
I am trying to check if the documentno is same in the response array and trying to push the corresponding item details in another array in my code(appcomponent.ts) but it is doing correctly can anyone help me to figure it out and how to do this

```
inq =[];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
          {
            var element=array[i];
            for(var j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
            {
              var elt =array[j];
              if(element.inquirydocno==elt.inquirydocno)
              {
                  this.inq.push(elt.Materialno);
                  this.inq.push(elt.Materialname);
                  
                  
              }
            }
            
          }
          console.log(this.inq);
```

I had attached an image of how my output should be displayed
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a dictionary for the 'details table'.

Something like this

```
export interface InquiryItem {
  materialNo: string[];
  materialName: string[];
}

inquiryItems: { [inquiryDocumentNo: string]: InquiryItem[] } = {};

// Manual populating
inquiryItems['001'] = [];
inquiryItems['002'] = [];
inquiryItems['001'].push({materialNo: '31', materialName: 'Book'});
inquiryItems["001"].push({materialNo: '31', materialName: 'Bag'});
inquiryItems["002"].push({materialNo: '30', materialName: 'Chair'});

// From response array
responseArray.forEach(entry => {
  const docNo = entry.InquiryDocumentNo;
  if(inquiryItems[docNo] === undefined)
    inquiryITems[docNo] = [];

  inquiryItems[docNo].push({
    materialNo: entry.Materialno;
    materialName: entry.Materialname;
  });
})

// Retrieval:
docItems: InquiryItem[] = inquiryItems['0010000015'];
```